# On the usage of clCreateImage2D

Tags: opencl

Usually the second parameter in  clCreateImage2D is a flag CL_MEM_READ etc. But I found it 0 in one of the sample codes (P. no: 80, Heterogeneous Computing using openCL  ):

```
 //Create space for the source image on the device
 cl_mem bufferSourceImage = clCreateImage2D(
 context,0,&format, width,height,0,NULL,NULL);
```

Why it is so?

Answer (score 2):

cl_mem_flags are bitfields:

cl.h

```
/* cl_mem_flags - bitfield */
#define CL_MEM_READ_WRITE                           (1 << 0)
#define CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY                           (1 << 1)
#define CL_MEM_READ_ONLY                            (1 << 2)
#define CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR                         (1 << 3)
#define CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR                       (1 << 4)
#define CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR                        (1 << 5)
// reserved                                         (1 << 6)    
#define CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY                      (1 << 7)
#define CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY                       (1 << 8)
#define CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS                       (1 << 9)
```

Here, 0 is a default value for CL_MEM_READ_WRITE :

> A bit-field that is used to specify allocation and usage information
>   such as the memory arena that should be used to allocate the buffer
>   object and how it will be used. The following table describes the
>   possible values for flags. If value specified for flags is 0, the
>   default is used which is CL_MEM_READ_WRITE.
>   From: [clCreateBuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html)

Comment: You are right, sorry. It's a default value. I edit my answer.